# pstricks is cropping my image too small

Tags: pstricks, crop

pstricks seems to automatically crop out all surrounding whitespace in an image. How can I stop this? For example, the code

```
\begin{pspicture}(-2, -2)(2, 2)
\psdots(0, 0)
\end{pspicture}
```

just produces a figure consisting entirely of the dot. How do I force pstricks to include the entire 4x4 region? I've tried `pspicture*` instead and adding a white frame around the image, but neither one worked.

Comment: It seems that this is due to your conversion chain. If you use `\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{pstricks}\begin{document}\begin{pspicture}(-2, -2)(2, 2)\psdots(0, 0)\end{pspicture}\end{document}` and run `xelatex`, you'll get your 4x4 area.

Comment: @marmot Argh, okay, thanks. I'm using `shell-escape` and the `auto-pst-pdf` package.

Answer (score 2):

Use `crop=off`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
X   
\begin{pspicture}(-2, -2)(2, 2)
\psdots(0, 0)
\end{pspicture}
X
\end{document}
```

[image]